# JAX-WS pass java object as parameter

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws

I've created a SOAP based web service using JAX-WS.

The `ParamMap` class extends `LinkedHashMap` and implements the `Map` interface.

I need to pass an object of this class as parameter in a method but when I am generating the classes from the wsdl I am not able to access extended methods of LinkedHashMap class like put, get etc.

This is my class:

```
package com.demo.clientutil.bean;

import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class ParamMap extends LinkedHashMap<String, String> implements Map<String, String> {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public ParamMap() {
    super();
}

public ParamMap(Map<String, String> map){
    super(map);
}
}
```

Comment: `ParamMap` class seems correct. Could you paste the code where you get the error?

Comment: @SatoshiKouno Thanks for reply, When I am generating classes from wsdl using wsimport command, ParamMap class is generated but methods of map interface like get, put are not available while creating object of ParamMap class in Client application